# Why is inet's SuperpositioningMobility module causing nodes to be placed outside of the constraint area during initialization?

Tags: omnet++, simulator, inet

I am putting together a demo of inet's mobility modules and am struggling with the Superpositioning Mobility module. When I attempt to run my simulation I get the following error message:

> Mobility position (x=1344.27,y=1102.76,z=0) is outside the constraint area (0,0,0 - 1000,1000,0) - in module(inet::SuperpositioningMobility) AntennaMovement.source.wlan[0].radio.antenna.mobility (id=88), during network initialization.

If I attempt to adjust the constraint area, the x and y coordinates shown in the error message also adjust such that they remain outside of the constraint area. I have included the code for the .ini file below. It is my goal to have the source node move around the area while the antenna's separate mobility module points in a fixed direction.

```
# Constraints
**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 1000m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 1000m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

# Source Mobility
*.source.mobility.typename = "LinearMobility"
*.source.mobility.initialMovementHeading = 200 deg
*.source.mobility.speed = 10mps

# Antenna Mobility
*.source.wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.typename = "SuperpositioningMobility"
*.source.wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.numElements = 2
*.source.wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.element[0].typename = "AttachedMobility"
*.source.wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.element[0].mobilityModule = "source.mobility"
*.source.wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.element[1].typename = "LinearMobility"
*.source.wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.element[1].initialMovementHeading = 100deg
```